# Using GPU with Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I am confused on the usage of .to(device) in pytorch. I know that it loads the variables to the GPU. But after that, lets say we multiply two gpu tensors together, will our computer know to use the gpu to do that? Or will it cast it back to CPU and preform the computation? I guess I am just confused on when and how our computer will know to use gpu outside of us telling it to hold some variable in its memory.

Comment: I believe once the variable has been moved to GPU, all operations that can be done on GPU will be done on GPU (not 100% sure on this :) )

Comment: @PlainRavioli that makes sense, thank you. It seems that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All operations on tensors that are e.g. in the GPU memory will be performed on the GPU. Furthermore if multiple tensors are involved in some operation, all of them need to be set to the same `.device`.

The way this is done is that no matter what operation we do to tensors, we'll always call methods of the `torch.Tensor` class. So adding two tensors `a + b` does actually call [`torch.Tensor.add`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.add.html), so whenever some operation is executed, it is always done with the knowledge of what device is used.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense. so if i make a variable `a` and set it equal to the sum of two gpu tensors, that variable 'a' will be automatically put on the gpu?

Comment: Exactly, otherwise you'd have to first transfer the result, which takes a lot of time. This is also the reason why you usually try to minimize the number of times to switch between gpu and cpu.